What is the Halacha if I pronounced הוליכך with a patach under the כ instead of a shva?
I realize that this question may be quite specific but this is something that I am genuinely concerned about and I am beating myself up for it.
I leined this Mincha on Shabbat. In the leining, I think I pronounced it as אשר הוליכַךָ instead of אשר הוליכְךָ (with a patach under the כ instead of a shva).
It may sound ridiculous but I feel like I may have invalidated the kriyah altogether because of that and I feel very sad about it and it's affecting my self-esteem.
What's the Halacha? Does it count as a kosher leining?

For practical matters, talk to your local rabbinic authority. But in Tiberian Hebrew at least, there is essentially no difference between most vocal shvas and a patach.

Yeah, you’re completely fine. In the pronunciation of the Tiberian Masorites—who invented the niqqud symbols to reflect their own system of pronunciation—Shva was pronounced as a short-Patach. (There are exceptions, but this isn’t one of them).
If you prolonged or stressed the Patach, the above would not apply, since in the Tiberian tradition, Shva was specifically pronounced very quickly.
However, there would still be no issue, for the simple reason that putting a Patach (or Kamatz, or Segol) in this location would not affect the meaning of the word. Originally, before the Masoretic era, the vowel before the ךָ suffix was always what we would call a Patach, regardless of pausal form. This vowel is also where the emphasis would fall (see row 4 in linked source, under PH and EBHP).
And remember: Even if you had made a real mistake, it’s fine. That’s how humans are. It’s wonderful that you care about doing this correctly, but please, don’t beat yourself up over it.

Okay, Baruch Hashem. Thank you so much

you didn't change a meaning to something else, so it is fine, but chataf patach under non גרוניות is just sheva with horizontal line indicating that sheva is נע and not נח at least according to תורת הקורא.
